# How to convert object dtype with value '$1.2M' to float dtype in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a column with currency type like $1.2K, $1.45M, etc as an Object dtype. I need to convert it to float value and create a new column Y. How can it be done using pandas?

Comment: how looks floats from data in question? `1.2, 1.45` ? Or `1200, 1450000` ?

Comment: The linked answer is only about removing the $ not about converting K to thoussands and M to millions.

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove $ sign as well need to convert K to Thousands and M to Millions